# Should have done something, and then

Tags: modal-verbs

If we describe some specific order of events after "should have" ("you should have done something, and then something), what form of the second verb should be used?

For example, "You should have talked to me first, and then **spend** all our savings on this stupid motorbike."

Spend? Have spent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the past participle form.  You don't need to repeat "have":

> You should have drunk your milk and eaten your biscuit.

The past participle form of spend is "spent".  But your sentence is odd, since it the speaker seems to suggest "you should have spent all our savings on this stupid motorbike"  That is odd.  Probably you mean

> You should have talked to me first before spending all our savings...

This carries the implication that you should *not* have spent the money without first talking to me.